# Search form Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, search, model-view-controller

I need to create search form to search for all the cases pt_name of the user

I got this error

> Couldn't find User with 'id'=

In cases controller

```
def index
    @user =User.find(params[:id])
    @cases=@user.cases
    if params[:search]
      @search_term = params[:search]
      @cases= @user.cases.casesearch_by(@search_term)
    end
  end
```

in case model

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.casesearch_by(search_term)
    where("LOWER(pt_name) LIKE :search_term OR LOWER(shade) LIKE :search_term",
     search_term: "%#{search_term.downcase}%")
  end
end
```

in cases index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for "",url: cases_path(@user.id), role: "search", method: :get  ,class: "navbar-form navbar-right" do %>
         <%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term,placeholder: "Search..."  %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first line in your controller.
When the form is submitted it's going to `cases_path(@user.id)` - that's what you specified in your form.

If you're checking with `rails routes` you'll see that cases_path is actually going to "/cases" (I am assuming you did not overwrite it) and that there isn't any placeholder for an id (like it would be for the show action for example which goes to "/cases/:id".

Now you still specify `@user.id` in `cases_path(@user.id)` and then you try to find a user with the id from the params. But if you check your params once you arrived in the controller (with binding.pry or other tools), you will see there is no key `:id` in the params. You can also check the url it is going to, I believe it will look something like this: "/cases.1".

You can solve that by changing the path to

```
cases_path(user_id: @user.id)
```

This way you add a new key value pair to the params hash and then in your controller you need to change it accordingly:

```
@user =User.find(params[:user_id])
```

You can also add a hidden field into your form in order to pass along the user id:

```
<%= form_for "", url: cases_path, role: "search", method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-right" do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term,placeholder: "Search..."  %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
 <% end %>
```

And then retrieve it in the controller.

To check your params that you get in the controller action use a gem like pry byebug or just the keyword `raise` and then inspect the `params` variable.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/cases?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=marah I still got this error Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Comment: You changed the path in the form? `<%= form_for "",url: cases_path(user_id: @user.id)` And it's not in the url?

Comment: <%= form_for "",url: cases_path(user_id: @user.id), role: "search", method: :get  ,class: "navbar-form navbar-right" do %>
         <%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term,placeholder: "Search..."  %>
        <% end %>

Comment: That is odd, I tried it in an app of mine and the user id was attached to the url. You can also add a hidden field - I edited my answer.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/cases?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=marah&user_id=2 still the same error

Comment: this one inside the controller def index
    @user =User.find(params[:id])

Comment: So weird. Sorry for asking basic questions but are you hard resfreshing the page when you fill in the form or are you using the back button of the browser by chance. And what happens if you add a debugger to the controller action

Comment: no that's fine i appreciate i. i dont have debugger. no its not hard to refresh the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222761/discussion-between-clara-and-nourza).